ERD notation for multiple connections to a single table
Assume I have a relational database with a User entity and a Friendship entity. The User entity has two connections to the Friendship entity (meaning two Users are part of a single Friendship). How would I note that relationship in an entity relationship diagram using Crow's Foot notation?

There are many ER & pseudo-ER methods & diagramming conventions. Give a reference for yours. Where are you stuck following it in what competent presentation/textbook? What does "connection" mean?--it isn't an ER term. PS Lines in ERDs & pseudo-ERDs do not generally represent relationships. In some ERDs they can. In some pseudo-ER methods they are said to represent relationships but don't but that's because there the methods call entity participations & FK constraints "relationships". which is not the "relationship" in ER/Entity-Relationship.
